# Proguard and Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, proguard, obfuscation

I have downloaded the plugin for Proguard in Netbeans. I cannot figure out how to actually obfuscate my code on the build though. Is there a way to configure netbeans so that it automatically obfuscates my code when I select the clean/build button? All other sources I found said I had to manipulate the xml files for my program. I don't want to do that if it's not necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Seriously, you should consider moving to Maven. There will a learning curve but after that you'll never have to ask such a question again.

Comment: @nolan6000 what all does that entail?